# Redirecting to some page when user hits site domain

Tags: force.com-sites

My site domain is suppose xyz.cs8.force.com now i want that whenever user hits this url he should be automatically redirected to xyz.cs8.force.com/Sitelogin which is the URL of my one custom site which i have created.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

When you are in production you can use the [Domain Management](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_mgmt_overview.htm&language=en_US) features of Salesforce and [create a custom URL](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_url_add.htm&language=en_US). You can map www.yourdomain.com to your site. **Custom domains are only supported in non sandbox environments**, though, so cs8 isn't going to work. You can also specify a Home Page Visualforce page on the site configuration as well, if you want it to go to a specific page.

So, for production www.yourdomain.com will go to the /yoursite site, but won't show the yoursite in the url. If you have a page, e.g., /yoursite/yourPage, that you see in your sandbox as /yourSite/yourPage it will show up in production as www.yourdomain.com/yourPage. If you want your www.yourdomain.com to automatically go to yourPage, make yourPage the Home Page in the Force.com Site configuration.